# ARM Cortex-M4 Interrupt priorities

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-m, irq, priority-inversion

I'm using an ARM Cortex-M4 MCU. If I have an interrupt handler for a GPIO at priority 2 and an SPI driver at priority 3 (i.e., lower priority than the GPIO's), and I call a (blocking) SPI read from within the GPIO's interrupt handler, will the SPI function work?

Comment: A blocking read (or blocking anything) in an interrupt handler is a really bad idea. Interrupts should always be as quick as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question depends on how it is blocking to handle the transfer, as @Notlikethat said.

If your SPI driver is a polling driver, then it will most likely work. In this case, your GPIO interrupt would spin on flags within the SPI peripheral, waiting for each part of the transfer to complete.

If your SPI driver is interrupt driven, then it will not work. Since you are executing a priority 2 interrupt (GPIO), the priority 3 interrupt (SPI) will not execute until the GPIO interrupt finishes. Depending on how your SPI driver is written, this may entirely hang your system, or it may result in a timeout.

If your SPI driver is DMA driven, then the answer is not so clear and depends on how the driver works. It is possible in this case, that your transaction would complete, but if the function has blocked waiting for a DMA interrupt, it may never arrive depending on its priority.

In any of the above cases, it would generally be considered not a good idea to do something like that inside of an interrupt. If you have an RTOS, you could use a high priority task that is waiting on a semaphore to execute the SPI transaction, or if the OS supports it, used deferred interrupt processing. If you aren't running with an RTOS, I would consider if there is a way you can signal a lower priority interrupt (i.e use PendSV at the lowest priority) or monitor a flag from within the main process. Using a lower priority interrupt, you can still preempt the main process (if that's what is needed), but all your other interrupts can continue executing. If you can monitor a flag in your main process, then that would also allow your interrupts to continue, but if you are time constrained, this may not be as possible (again, depending on how your application is structured)